# How to find missing date rows in a sequence using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with more than `4 million rows and 30 columns`. I am just providing a sample of my patient dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'subject_ID':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3],
    'date_visit':['1/1/2020 12:35:21','1/1/2020 14:35:32','1/1/2020 16:21:20','01/02/2020 15:12:37','01/03/2020 16:32:12',
                 '1/1/2020 12:35:21','1/3/2020 14:35:32','1/8/2020 16:21:20','01/09/2020 15:12:37','01/10/2020 16:32:12',
                 '11/01/2022 13:02:31','13/01/2023 17:12:31','16/01/2023 19:22:31'],
    'item_name':['PEEP','Fio2','PEEP','Fio2','PEEP','PEEP','PEEP','PEEP','PEEP','PEEP','Fio2','Fio2','Fio2']})
```

I would like to do two things

1) Find the subjects and their records which are missing in the sequence

2) Get the count of `item_name` for each subjects

For `q2`, this is what I tried

```
df.groupby(['subject_ID','item_name']).count()  # though this produces output, column name is not okay. I mean why do it show the count value on `date_visit` column?
```

For `q1`, this is what I am trying

```
df['day'].le(df['shift_date'].add(1))
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Comment: what defines a missing date?

Comment: For example. `subject_id = 2 has records only for dates 1,3,8,9,10`. Through this we  can infer that his records for dates `2,4,5,6,7` are missing.

Comment: If you see `subject_id = 1 you can see that he/she has records continuously. There is no break in between their dates`. That's why `Seq_status = Yes` indicating he/she is in Sequence

Comment: @Datanovice - updated the sample dataframe and expected output.There was minor change.

Comment: @SSMK do you want the missing dates or just the total of them?

Comment: I want the missing dates for each subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the first part with:

```
In [14]: df.groupby("subject_ID")['item_name'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
Out[14]:
item_name   Fio2  PEEP
subject_ID
1              2     3
2              0     5
3              3     0
```

EDIT:

I think you've still got your date formats a bit messed up in your sample output, and strongly recommend switching everything to the ISO 8601 standard since that prevents problems like that down the road. `pandas` won't correctly parse that `11/01/2022` entry on its own, so I've manually fixed it in the sample.

Using what I assume these dates are supposed to be, you can find the gaps by grouping and using `.resample()`:

```
In [73]: df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_visit'])

In [74]: df.loc[10, 'dates'] = pd.to_datetime("2022-01-11 13:02:31")

In [75]: dates = df.groupby("subject_ID").apply(lambda x: x.set_index('dates').resample('D').first())

In [76]: dates.index[dates.isnull().any(axis=1)].to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)
Out[76]:
   subject_ID      dates
0           2 2020-01-02
1           2 2020-01-04
2           2 2020-01-05
3           2 2020-01-06
4           2 2020-01-07
5           3 2022-01-12
6           3 2022-01-14
7           3 2022-01-15
```

You can then add `seq status` to that first frame by checking whether the ID shows up in this new frame.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Upvoted. For 2nd part, please refer the dates in sample dataframe. I would like to get the missing dates for each subject

Comment: Yeah, I do see the dates there, but the logic is unclear. I'm assuming these are European formatted by the 13/01, but if subject 3 starts at Jan 11, why are the missing dates all in November? FWIW, would recommend switching all of these to ISO date format to make them unambiguous.

Comment: Sorry, updated the expected output and sample dataframe. Dates are in the format `day/month/year`

Comment: Apologies for the delay. Marked the answer